# Getting height of a wxWidgets panel which is not fully visible

Tags: perl, wxwidgets

I use ***wxWidgets*** and implement scrollbars in my simple application, and for correct scrollbar initialization I need to know the total height of widgets inside the scrolled area.

I'm unable get the correct height of widgets which are not completely visible.

Is there some way to get the height of theses hidden items?

[image: image from imgur.com]

Comment: You can't get the height/width of the control (whatever "control" is) if this control is not realized completely. System does not know about it yet. And even if this information would be available - it will not be portable as GTK sizes are available ONLY for the realized windows.

Comment: Are you sure you need this?  The scrollbars should be set up correctly without yours handling it manually, with `wxWidgets` as well as any other toolkit. There are options for how they'll behave though. Is there something very special that you want to do?

Comment: @zdim I think I need this information. I use wxVScrolledWindow class [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_v_scrolled_window.html). When you want to use this class you need need to derive from it and implement the OnGetRowHeight() pure virtual method. You also must call SetRowCount() to let the base class know how many rows it should display...

Comment: A quick look at linked docs shows -- "_not necessary to know the heights of all rows in advance – only those which are shown on the screen need to be measured;_" and later is says that "_You only need to draw the visible part of contents_".  This makes sense, getting the hidden part doesn't, since it's not realized. Is it this that you are still having a problem with?  I am not sure what you mean by "_unable get the correct height of widgets_". I'll look into it if/when I can.

Comment: `GetSize()` always returns the correct value, whether a widget is hidden or not, so whatever it returns is the real height of your panel. You don't explain at all what are you doing, so it's impossible to even understand what the real problem is, let alone how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetSize() method returned correct dimensions. Problem was using wxScrolledWindow class, because "panels" inside **wxScrolledWindow** only had dimensions such as the dimension of visible part of the wxScrolleWindow. Thus, method GetSize() seemed to be returning wrong height. Complete solution of this problem is desribed here [Resize a wxNotebook when content sizes changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846567/resize-a-wxnotebook-when-content-sizes-changed)